# How to add weights to dataset variables using kNN in Octave?

Tags: algorithm, knn

I am implementing [this kNN](https://github.com/markuman/fastKNN)  algorithm in Octave.

The function itself is declared like this

```
    function [classified, k, dist, idx] = fastKNN(trained, unknown, k, distance)
```

My dataset is this:

```
%lat, lng, area, buildyear, price
54.6, 24.7, 23.6, 1965, 100000.00
54.6, 24.7, 13.6, 1964, 50000.00
...
```

I have 2 questions.

**Question 1:**  How do I add weights to the dataset variables. For example area has a much bigger weight than coordinates.

**Question 2:** I if set k=3, does the algorithm return to me the avg price of the closest 3 neighbors or it picks one from the 3? - I guess this is more related to the algorithm I am learning.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put more weight on one feature, you can *multiply* the given feature by a certain value.

This is equivalent to stretching the space along the respective dimension, effectively putting more emphasis on changes in the respective feature when the distances are calculated.

---

The [fastKnn](https://github.com/markuman/fastKNN/blob/master/fastKNN.m) function that you mentioned uses the "mode" of the nearest k neighbors (*i.e.* the most frequent value). This is appropriate for classification (where you have a few classes that you want to predict), but not very useful for your situation.

For regression, taking the average of the values of the nearest neighbors is a good choice.